# showing 2 datagridviews one is depended from another

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello I have made in Entity Framework 2 tables

One is Student and another is Courses

I made a one to many relationship

A student can follow one course and a course has one ore more students

In my GUI form I like to show my students in one datagridview and courses (in another datagridview) depended from the selected student.

I don't know how to show that.
Can somebody help me please?

```
 SchoolContainer dbSchool = new SchoolContainer();
    private void frmSchool_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgStudent.DataSource = dbSchool.Students.ToList();
        bnStudent.BindingSource = new BindingSource(dgStudent.DataSource, null);
    }
```

Here I don't know what to write:

```
  private void dgStudent_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*Dependent from selected student show the courses */
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this problem in the wrong fashion.

This YouTube tutorial is exactly what your looking to achieve. You just need to filter your datagridview by setting up a rowfilter.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_K__V0rIz4

This will help.

Comment: Hi derek,I'm not sure but I have read that it's superfluous by using datasets in Entity framework because they are already objects...
I don't find where I read it

Comment: Its not the Datasets that your looking at, its how he is filtering one datagridview from selecting rows in another.

Comment: If I not work with datasets and only with datagridview how can I apply this in my code?